# I need to call a function until it returns 0 in python

Tags: python, loops

```
def solveMaze(win, board):  
    mazesol.removeDeadEnds(win, board)
```

I need to call `mazesol.removeDeadends(win,board)` until it returns `0`. This is what the function does:

This function takes the window as its first argument and the board as its second argument. It sweeps the complete board (skipping the first and last rows and the first and last columns), and converts every position that is a path with exactly one path as a neighbor into a dead end. It returns the number of dead ends that were converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
while mazesol.removeDeadEnds(win, board) != 0:
    pass
```

Answer (score 8):

Is there something wrong with:

```
while mazesol.removeDeadends(win,board): pass
```

or

```
while mazesol.removeDeadends(win,board): print ".",
```

or

```
 a = 1
 while a:
   a = mazesol.removeDeadends(win,board)
   print "Removed", a
```

Comment: I edited your answer - you should use the "code" button instead of the "quote" button for code formatting, as it provides syntax highlighting as well.

Comment: I was editing it at the same time.  Should have looked at the preview.

Comment: Although I know this probably wouldn't matter in practice, if `removeDeadends` could return non-numeric values then there's a chance that the first loop could terminate prematurely, e.g. if the function returns `False`. That's why I used `!= 0` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

fast and dirty

```
result = mazesol.removeDeadends(win,board)
while not result:
  result = mazesol.removeDeadends(win,board)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an infinite while loop that breaks if 0 is returned:

```
While True:
    result = mazesol.removeDeadends(win,board)
    if result == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in iter(partial(mazesol.removeDeadends, win, board), 0):
   pass
```

`iter` has a second form that allows you to pass a callable and a setinel value. What's cool is that if you need to, you can loop over the response since it's now an iterable.